# JsonResult returning empty Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JsonResult in my controller:

```
public JsonResult SearchRxNormDrugs(string term)
{
    var matches = rxnConsoService.SearchRxNormDrugs(term);

    return Json(matches, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When debugging the project I can see that `matches` has 300+ results in it. All of the matches have content in them as well. However, when I navigate to this action in the url, the result I get back is the following:

(Click the image to see it full size)
[image]

Model:

```
public class RxNConso
{
    [KeyProperty(Identity = true)]
    string RXCUI { get; set; }
    string LAT { get; set; }
    string TS { get; set; }
    string LUI { get; set; }
    string STT { get; set; }
    string SUI { get; set; }
    string ISPREF { get; set; }
    string RXAUI { get; set; }
    string SAUI { get; set; }
    string SCUI { get; set; }
    string SDUI { get; set; }
    string SAB { get; set; }
    string TTY { get; set; }
    string CODE { get; set; }
    string STR { get; set; }
    string SRL { get; set; }
    string SUPPRESS { get; set; }
    string CVF { get; set; }
}
```

`matches` is an `IEnumerable` of `RxNConso`

```
IEnumerable<RxNConso> matches
```

Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: Looks like your JSON result has "300+" results in it as well (I didn't count them...) - ie it's the same as `matches`.   You need to check what the content of some of the matches is, not just that there's 300 of them.  eg try this: `var m = matches.First();return Json(m, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`  (depends on type of matches)

Comment: @freedomn-m All of the results/matches have content in them, I should have added that to the original post. I'll do that now. That's what's confusing me though.

Comment: Can we see the class that you're trying to serialize?

Comment: What is the Type of matches? Make sure it is not a plain `List<object>`, because objects might get serialized in that way...

Comment: Are your properties/fields private?

Comment: @krillgar Added more information to the post.

Comment: @Dygestor Added more information to the post.

Comment: @Rob Silly enough, that was my issue. I'm not sure why I didn't catch that much sooner. If you could reply with that as an answer, I would happily accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most serialization libraries only care about publicly accessible properties/fields. It's likely your class only has private fields/properties, which would explain why you can see the values in the debugger, but get an empty result while serializing.

Comment: After adding more information to my post I realized that my properties in my 'Model' were not made public. That fixed the issue, thanks!